# Weird NSDictionary crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]
          initWithObjectsAndKeys:myarray1, @"array1", myarray2, @"array2" nil];

NSArray *shorts =[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (NSString *dir in shorts) {
    NSArray *tempArr = [dict objectForKey:dir];
    for (NSString *file in tempArr ) {
        NSLog(@"%@", file);
    }
}
```

Where myarray1 and myarray2 are NSArrays.

When I execute the code the application crashes with:

```
-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d134
```

This is apparently the tempArr, which is not recognized as an NSArray. I know that `[dicFiles objectForKey:dir]` returns an `id` type object, but as a generic type, I cannot get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the code that initializes `myarray1` and `myarray2`, but apparently one or both of them are instances of `NSString` rather than `NSArray`. You can check that after retrieving one of the objects from the array as follows:

```
if (![tempArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to process temp array because it's an instance of %@", [tempArr class]);
}
else
{
    // for loop code goes here...
}
```

Comment: When you see an 'unrecognized selector' error message, you're in luck, because the message tells you exactly what went wrong. In this case the framework was trying to send a private variant of `-count` -- an `NSArray` message -- to an instance of `NSCFString` (a private subclass of `NSString`).

Comment: Many thaks for this notice ! Its really helpful